# Why do movie credits scroll while TV credits show static frames?

Tags: credits

Usually the end credits in a movie are usually shown as a scrolling list (some movies show the names of major cast and crew with fancy animations but they subsequently turn into the scrolling list pretty soon), while end credits for a TV episode usually show static frames containing the names one after another. Is there a reason for this convention (practical or otherwise), or is it that the convention just happens to be this way?

Comment: Because on TV time in an important factor. Flashing a page is a lot quicker than scrolling the page.

Comment: This isn't actually the case. I've seen each format used regardless of whether it was film or tv.

Comment: @sanpaco: The OP writes "usually", not "always". Exceptions notwithstanding, I think the convention as they describe it is generally correct.

Comment: I still think this question borders on being opinion-based or too broad in my view the way it is written. I don't think it's necessarily evident, nor has it been well established in the question, that tv shows use one form of credits vs film. Whether its always or "usually".

Comment: What I personally have seen more commonly regardless of whether its tv or film is that the initial credits are shows as cards (announcing main stars, director, producers, etc) and then are followed by the full credits including the entire cast, editing crews, stage crews, grips, etc etc etc.

Comment: This has changed a lot over time, with American movies in the 40s having very few credits. It's also likely to vary internationally and between production studios. And some TV programs try to look like movies. There are vastly different technical limitations between old TV (analog/UHF/CRT) and new (digital encoding/digital display), or between cinema in the 1930s and today. This risks turning into a complete history of film and TV. But at the same time, there may be a valid question in there, if it can be narrowed down.